# How do you access your php files on a domain that is hosted?

Tags: php, hosting

I have been doing some local hosting using MAMP, and accessing my database through php files stored on my local host. My testing is done and I've moved my php files to a godaddy server. I'm trying to change my c# code to *run the php files at their new location but I keep getting a "File Not Found" error. the domain of the site is assassintag.com, and I stored the php files in the public_html folder.
[image]

In my code I've tried accessing using the links:

```
www.assassintag.com/phpfilename.php
http://assassintag.com/phpfilename.php
http://www.assassintag.com/phpfilename.php
```

none of these work. I'm not new to coding, but I'm very new to hosting php files on a server. Any help and pointers would be wonderful. Thanks

Comment: If you want to access the raw PHP source code, you will need to use an authenticated connection like SFTP.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I'll edit my question. I just want to run the php code.

Comment: You said you recently transferred them all, make sure that you update your file src's as I'm sure they would've changed location as you've just migrated everything, that might be why

Comment: I did switch the file srcs.... my questions is that I don't know what the new src's should be.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was simple. Using MAMP, The URLS I submitted were case insensitive, so I used all lowercase. Now that the files are hosted online, the file names are now case sensitive. After I added camel casing to my URLs in my code, everything worked fine.